# Lowerbounds for in-situ permutation

Tags: ds.algorithms, lower-bounds, permutations

What is the best known lowerbound for the worst case complexity of in-situ permutation (also called in-place rearrangement)? Has there been any reported progress after the 1970's article by Knuth (which also appears as Chapter 1 of his book "Selected Papers on Analysis of Algorithms")?

Comment: related unanswered question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/6711/1037